# Question edited by low rep user

Tags: discussion, edits, new-users

I just noticed on the question [<li> looking bizarre on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146031/li-looking-bizarre-on-ie) that the question had been edited by a user with rep score 47.

How is that even possible, aren't 2000 rep necessary? Unless he somehow lost 1950+ points within the last 50 minutes, but that would be surprising.

Comment: Haven't you looked at the front page of Meta today?  Someone losing 1950 rep in the last 50 minutes would not be that surprising.  ;)

Comment: Speaking of `<li>` looking bizarre on IE, does this question [render like this](http://i.imgur.com/A5mv4.png) for anyone else?

Comment: I edited it again, since his edit made your HTML invalid

Comment: Most people losing rep today lost a few hundreds, that's why 2000 would be more surprising imho, especially if the final score is less than 50 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can edit anything, the edit needs to be approved by a mod ;)

Answer (score 5):

The whole process is described [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/). With pictures :)

PS You don't have to be a mod to approve edits, sufficient reputation will do. As I understand, you need 2k to approve post edits, 5k to approve tag wiki edits and 10k to see [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) page.

Comment: Actually you just need the rep to edit to be able to approve an edit.  So you just need 2k rep.

Comment: Yep, 5K: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

Comment: Oh, yeah, @jzd is right, my link is about the tag wiki edits... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

An edit can be proposed by any user now, but the edits proposed by people of less than 2K must be confirmed by the user, or a mod, prior to the edit appearing.